# Minecraft mining speeds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the mining speeds of some of the blocks

Because the only thing that I saw was that cobble takes 2 times as longer to mine then to mine wood.

Comment: Are you using tools? Or just your fists?

Comment: "some of the blocks" is pretty vague. What do you have an issue with? And using the right tool, mining stone can be way faster then mining wood.

Answer (score 5):

Blocks vary depending on what you are using to break them down.

For example a diamond pick on cobblestone will always be a lot faster than a wooden one, same goes for axes and most other tools.

There is a table on [pickaxes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe) here.

It indicates, for example, it takes a Diamond pick 0.4s to mine cobblestone, but a wooden one takes 1.5s.

Using the correct tool will also speed up the process, eg an axe for woods, pick for cobblestone.